# C# Reflection DateTime?

Tags: c#

I can't find anything on the net that will help me figure this out, if someone could please help you would be a lifesaver.

my function is given a property name and the object. Using reflection it returns the value of that property. It works perfectly however if i pass it a Nullable DateTime it gives me null and no matter what i try i cant get it to work.

```
public static string GetPropValue(String name, Object obj)
{
 Type type = obj.GetType();
 System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(name);
 if (info == null) { return null; }
 obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
 return obj.ToString();
 }
```

in the above function obj is null. How do i get it to read the DateTime?

Comment: Well, did the `Nullable<DateTime>` have a non-null value?

Comment: I'm sorry are you asking how to get the date value of a null?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine-- this prints the time of day:

```
class Program
{
    public static string GetPropValue(String name, Object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(name);
        if (info == null) { return null; }
        obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
        return obj.ToString();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt = GetPropValue("DtProp", new { DtProp = (DateTime?) DateTime.Now});
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```

To avoid an exception for a null value, change the last line of `GetPropValue` to:

```
return obj == null ? "(null)" : obj.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me..

Are you sure your PropertyInfo is returning a non null ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
        Type t = typeof(MyClass);
        PropertyInfo pi= t.GetProperty("CurrentTime");
        object temp= pi.GetValue(mc, null);
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
public class MyClass
{
    private DateTime? currentTime;

    public DateTime? CurrentTime
    {
        get { return currentTime; }
        set { currentTime = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nullable type is of the type [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and has two properties: `HasValue` and `Value`. You first need to check `HasValue` to check if `Value` is set, then you can access the actual data from `Value`.

Either <s>you check whether the given object is a `Nullable<T>` and do these checks in your `GetPropValue`</s>, or you do this logic outside of this method and make sure you invoke it with a non-nullable value.

**EDIT** Scratch that, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx) `GetType()` always gives you the underlying type. Are you sure you're passing a non-null object?